# Etherum addresses confusion, How does it acutally works?

Tags: accounts

There are so many wallet websites ..wallet apps and then there is metamask ..my question is when ever we create a wallet account all these are ethereum addresses/accounts are created on the live Ethereum blockchain?

Also if a account is created on Ropsten or other networks can i get ethers in that from a live ethereum network and is it valid? or i should be careful when sharing my ethereum address and make sure it is from the real live network.

Please guide

Answer (score 2):

Test networks like Ropsten and Rinkeby simulate the ethereum blockchain and are isolated to their respective network. That means you can't transfer ether from the mainnet to the testnets and vice versa.

Most wallets allow you to choose whether or not you want to be on the mainnet or testnets when creating an account. So if you're on a testnet and create an account, that address will belong to that testnet and not the live ethereum blockchain.